# "The machine with the name 'c6401' was not found configured for this Vagrant environment." Error

Tags: apache, hadoop, vagrant

I plan to work with Apache Ambari. To start, I've done everything according to https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Quick+Start+Guide. But whenever I try to start vms, I get following error:

```
The machine with the name 'c6401' was not found configured for
this Vagrant environment.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had this error today on mac and decided to update this post with the solution that worked for me.

Steps

1. Delete all redundant machine folders ./.vagrant/machines (.vagrant folder is a hidden folder within the repo)
2. Run `vagrant global-status --prune` command in the root of the project
3. Destroy vagrant setup `vagrant destroy`
4. Ensure no related machine exists in the virtualbox UI
5. Run `vagrant up` again

cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Please open the VagrantFile under the centos6.4 directory and verify if you see contents like this:

```
  config.vm.define :c6401 do |c6401|
# uncomment the line below to set up the ambari dev environment
# c6401.vm.provision :shell, :path => "dev-bootstrap.sh"
c6401.vm.hostname = "c6401.ambari.apache.org"
c6401.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.64.101"
end
```

I had faced a similar issue. The problem was that I had deleted the Vagrantfile that comes by default with ambari-vagrant.git and had run 'vagrant init', which creates a standard template file that doesn't have any reference to c6401 machine.
If you are on the same boat, just do a

```
git checkout centos6.4/VagrantFile
```

from under ambari-vagrant directory and try re-running

```
vagrant up c6401
```